# Bean validation in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bean-validation

I'm using Bean Validation in my Java project, with the version being 4.2.0.

I'd like to enable the Bean Validation facet in IntelliJ Idea (version 10.5.2), but the only option that appears is 4.0.0.Beta2. If I select that, it complains that the JAR is not present.

Is there a way to make Idea use version 4.2.0 of the BV framework?

I don't know if it's needed, but I'm also using Spring 3 (no EJB) and Hibernate 3.6.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luciano, please open an issue in IntelliJ IDEA tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.net. We will fix it asap.